# Recommended ways to manage / edit files on Amazon EFS remotely?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-efs

We're starting to use AWS, making use of EFS for application / user data and configuration.  Now I wonder what are good ways to access and manage these files remotely, for instance in order to

- edit a configuration file on EFS,
- move / rename files on EFS,
- create backup copies,
- upload additional files,
- overwriting existing ones with updated versions, or to
- download data created with applications running on AWS.

I can see the following options:

1. Using a cheap EC2 instance with SSH access to edit and manage files remotely.
2. Mounting the EFS into an on premise Linux machine via NFS4, requiring VPN or "Direct Connect".
3. Starting a web app on AWS for web-based file management.

I had previously looked into the latter, and found the following (list is about a year old):

- https://github.com/mickael-kerjean/filestash (Go, lots of data backends including S3, Dropbox, Google Drive)
- https://github.com/kalcaddle/KodExplorer (PHP, open source)
- https://www.filerun.com/ (PHP, obfuscated / not OSS)
- https://filebrowser.xyz/ (Go, VueJS, only filesystem backend?)
- https://github.com/subnub/myDrive (Node.js, Typescript, MongoDB for metadata, chunks stored in S3, MongoDB, or filesystem)

My hunch is that the second option (NFS mounting) may be relatively complex and expensive, and that SSH/SCP access may be preferred for us, but I'd like to know what solutions others use.

Oh, a fourth way could be a file synchronization service, of course.

Comment: Dare to elaborate on the use case and the requirements? What do you want to achieve? Having a file server in AWS for a local use in the office doesn’t make much sense.

Comment: Yes, thank you for the question – I edited my question to elaborate on the file management actions I would like to be able to do conveniently on EFS.